# docker services.web.working_dir contains an invalid type, it should be a string

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am trying to up phpserver via docker-compose.
I put 3 files in my working directory.

.env
docker-compose.yml
Dockerfile

.env

```
##PATHS

DB_PATH_HOST=./databases
APP_PATH_HOST=./blog
APP_PATH_CONTAINER=/var/www/html/
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
```

docker-compose.yml

version: '3'

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    working_dir:
      - ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ${DB_PATH_HOST}: /var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6080:8080
  composer:
    image: composer:1.7
    volumes:
      - ${APP_PATH_HOST}: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    command: composer install
```

and Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install \
     pdo_mysql \
     && a2enmod
     rewrite
```

---

But after I try to run

```
docker-compose up --build
```

I have the problem

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.web.working_dir contains an invalid type, it should be a string
services.composer.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be a string
services.web.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be a string
services.db.volumes contains an invalid type, it should be a string
```

I tried to change docker-compose file version  to 2  - does not work
I tried to use '' and "" the same problem.

I want to run my server successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
    volumes:
      - "${APP_PATH_HOST}: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}"
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - "${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql"

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6080:8080
  composer:
    image: composer:1.7
    volumes:
      - "${APP_PATH_HOST}: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}"
    working_dir: ${APP_PATH_CONTAINER}
    command: composer install
```

What you used for working_dir was a list. It needed a string.

Comment: As I sad before I use "" but problem has not gone.

Comment: Use the version in my answer exactly how it is. It works and your problem will go

Answer (score 8):

The following two formats work:

Format #1

```
environment:
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpassword
```

Format #2

```
environment:
  - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpassword
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to connect to from adminer to postgres
    version: '3'

```
services:
  web:
    build: .
    environment:
      - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
    volumes:
      - ./blog:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: kisphp
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_DB: kisphp
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "6080:8080"
```

and I have next error.

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "root"
```

Comment: This is not really an answer. Maybe you can ask a new question? and also you should give more details about the error: when exactly is it happening for example. I see you set your ROOT password in only 1 place for the database. Where do you set it for the application connecting to the database?

Comment: I now notice you changed the database as well :) Please ask a different question with this data